# Gitlab Pipelines Stages take hours or days to show result (passed, failed) - docker, node app

Tags: node.js, docker, gitlab, docker-compose, gitlab-ci

I'm using Gitlab continuous integration (.gitlab-ci.yml) and docker, docker-compose to build, test and deploy my node app, but build and test takes so much time to complete on gitlab pipeline (in my local docker app builds and tests are running smoothly), I think this is not normal behavior of gitlab ci and i think i'm missing something or i'm using a wrong configuration

please check the configuration (.gitlab-ci.yml) below and screen shot of pipelines at the bottom

.gitlab-ci.yml

```
# GitLab CI Docker Image
image: node:6.10.0

# Build - Build necessary JS files
# Test - Run tests
# Deploy - Deploy application to ElasticBeanstalk
stages:
  - build
  - test
  - deploy

# Configuration
variables:
  POSTGRES_DB: f_ci
  POSTGRES_USER: f_user
  POSTGRES_PASSWORD: sucof

services:
  - postgres:latest

cache:
  paths:
  - node_modules/

# Job: Build
# Installs npm packages
# Passes node_modules/ onto next steps using artifacts
build:linux:
  stage: build
  script:
    - npm install
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - node_modules/
  tags:
    - f-api

# Job: Test
# Run tests against our application
# If this fails, we do not deploy
test:linux:
  stage: test
  variables:
    NODE_ENV: continuous_integration  
  script:
    - ./node_modules/.bin/sequelize db:migrate --env=continuous_integration
    - ./node_modules/.bin/sequelize db:seed:all --env=continuous_integration
    - npm test
  tags:
    - f-api


# Job: Deploy
# Staging environment
deploy:staging:aws:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - apt-get update -qq
    - apt-get -qq install python3 python3-dev
    - curl -O https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py
    - python3 get-pip.py
    - pip install awsebcli --upgrade
    - mkdir ~/.aws/
    - touch ~/.aws/credentials
    - printf "[default]\naws_access_key_id = %s\naws_secret_access_key = %s\n" "$AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID" "$AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY" >> ~/.aws/credentials
    - touch ~/.aws/config
    - printf "[profile adm-eb-cli]\naws_access_key_id = %s\naws_secret_access_key = %s\n" "$AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID" "$AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY" >> ~/.aws/config
    - eb deploy f-api-stg
  environment:
    name: staging
    url: http://f-api-stg.gxnvwbgfma.ap-southeast-1.elasticbeanstalk.com
  tags:
    - f-api
  only:
    - staging

# Job: Deploy
# Production environment
deploy:prod:aws:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - echo "Deploy to production server"
  environment:
    name: production
    url: http://f-api.gxnvwbgfma.ap-southeast-1.elasticbeanstalk.com
  when: manual
  tags:
    - f-api
  only:
    - master
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM node:6.10.0

MAINTAINER Theodore GARSON-CORBEAUX <tgcorbeaux@maltem.com>

# Create app directory
ENV HOME=/usr/src/app
RUN mkdir -p $HOME
WORKDIR $HOME

# Install api dependencies
ADD package.json /usr/src/app/package.json
RUN npm install
ADD . /usr/src/app

EXPOSE 3000

CMD ["npm","start"]
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "2.1"

services:

  db_dev:
    image: postgres:latest
    ports:
      - "49170:5432"
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=f_user
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=pass
      - POSTGRES_DB=f_dev
    healthcheck:
      test: "exit 0"

  db_test:
    image: postgres:latest
    ports:
      - "49171:5432"
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=f_user
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=pass
      - POSTGRES_DB=f_test
    healthcheck:
      test: "exit 0"

  app:
    build: .
    environment:
      - NODE_ENV=development     
    command: "npm start"
    ports:
      - "49160:3000"
    depends_on:
      db_dev:
        condition: service_healthy

  migrate:
    build: .
    environment:
      - NODE_ENV
    command: "./node_modules/.bin/sequelize db:migrate --env ${NODE_ENV}"
    depends_on:
      db_dev:
        condition: service_healthy
      db_test:
        condition: service_healthy
    healthcheck:
      test: "exit 0"

  populate_db:
    build: .
    environment:
      - NODE_ENV
    command: "./node_modules/.bin/sequelize db:seed:all --env ${NODE_ENV}"
    depends_on:
      migrate:
        condition: service_healthy
    healthcheck:
      test: "exit 0"

  depopulate_db:
    build: .
    environment:
      - NODE_ENV
    command: "./node_modules/.bin/sequelize db:seed:undo:all --env ${NODE_ENV}"
    depends_on:
      migrate:
        condition: service_healthy
    healthcheck:
      test: "exit 0"

  test:
    build: .
    environment:
      - NODE_ENV=test  
    command: "npm test"
    depends_on:
      populate_db:
        condition: service_healthy
```

[image]

Comment: And what is your runner configuration? Are you sure the runner tagged `f-api` is free?

Comment: how can i check the runner configuration? and how can i check if it's free or is there a way to point to a local runner? (thank you for your reply i think this is the right direction)

Comment: i get 31;1mERROR: Registering runner... forbidden (check registration token) , i followed this guide https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/install/windows.html C:\GitLab-Runner>gitlab-runner register
Please enter the gitlab-ci coordinator URL (e.g. https://gitlab.com/):
https://gitlab.com
Please enter the gitlab-ci token for this runner:
xxxx (To register a new Runner you should enter the following registration token. With this token the Runner will request a unique Runner token and use that for future communication. 
Registration token is  xCSh1DcSMxD96qpJxb7p)

Comment: exact error is: [31;1mERROR: Registering runner... forbidden (check registration token)[0;m  [31;1mrunner[0;m=yHEmnJ4_
[31;1mPANIC: Failed to register this runner. Perhaps you are having network problems[0;m

Comment: Well, it seems you can't run it on the tagged runner because it won't register. You could remove the tag from .gitlab-ci.yml if you have other runners. Otherwise then that I'm afraid I don't know how to help you, you should try asking a new question about that specific error.

Comment: thank you for the response, i found in gitlab had runner token in two places (1. in admin area, 2. project settings drop down)

Comment: so i tried to register runner in my local windows 10 machine using the admin are runner token and it failed, then i tried to registered a runner from my same machine using  runner token in project setting drop down, it was successful, but seems like gitlab windows runner only supports shell executor so i have new issues now, any way i'll create a new question as you suggested for those, thank you for your pointers